# Render multiple pages in SSRS report into single page

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, business-intelligence

I have a SSRS report to show values from a stored procedure in SQL Server Business Intelligence Studio. The stored procedure will return 120 rows, each row will be displayed as a table format in my report.

So now I have 120 pages, each page having one table equivalent to a row in the stored procedure. I want 4 tables on every single page, so that there should be 30 pages in the SSRS report, with each page having 4 tables that is 4 rows from the stored procedure.

I have added grouping and page breaks but it did not help. Can you please help me.?

Currently I have

[image: Currently I have]

Actually I want like this

[image: Actually I want like this]

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the code of your report. Inside `<Page></Page>.`

It should be like this:

```
<Page>
    <InteractiveHeight>0in</InteractiveHeight>
    <InteractiveWidth>8.5in</InteractiveWidth>
</Page>
```

Change the InteractiveHeight value. You can notice that I just put 0in on it. That means, there will be no height limit. The report will just always show in just 1 page. Measure/Estimate the report's Height by inches to show only 4 tables per page of your report.

In case you're not familiar how to view the code of you report, Just follow the below steps.

```
1. Go to Solution Explorer. 
2. Right Click the report.
3. Click View Code
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, But I want to show that in the tabular form 2*2 matrix form(See the image). Can you say how that can be done

Comment: Are your tables dynamic? I mean are they on a loop or you setup 120 tables separately?

Comment: No, Its a static table. Instead of viewing in a column name value format (Default view in SSRS like Excel) we are using a different format thats all. I have added the images please refer that too.

Answer (score 0):

you can change your proc to add a grouping column, and a table column, something like this

```
    *group, table,row columns*
    group1, table1,row1
    group1, table2,row2
    group1, table3,row3
    group1, table4,row4
    group2, table1,row5
    group2, table2,row6
    group2, table3,row7
    group2, table4,row8
    ..
```

you will need some manipulating the sql to achieve this, but doable.

Then in your ssrs report, put a list object, the list will group on the group column defined above. Add 4 tables in 2 x 2 format into a rectangle object (rectangle is to keep the tables together), each table will have a filter (in properties) (table 1: table = table, table 2: table = table etc),  then add the rectangle into the list. In the group properties of the list, check break between groups. Now your page will be based on the groups you defined. And each table in the same group(page) will only show data based on the filter.